# Flutter Google Sign In Couchbase Authentication Code Flow

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, openid-connect, couchbase-sync-gateway

As we are migrating our app from Firebase to Couchbase, we also need to change the authentication part. We are using the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package and would like to continue using it to have the native Google Sign In popup. Using the package we can get a `serverAuthCode`, which from my understanding we can then send to the [_oidc_callback endpoint of Couchbase Sync Gateway](https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/current/rest-api-admin.html). First I had to set `disable_callback_state` to true in the Sync Gateway configuration ("[DisableCallbackState determines whether or not to maintain state between the /_oidc and /_oidc_callback endpoints.](https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/current/configuration-schema-database.html)"). However, when I now send the `serverAuthCode` to the `_oidc_callback` endpoint, I get the following error with status code 500:

`body: {"error": "Internal Server Error", "reason": "Failed to exchange token: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request\nResponse: {\n \"error\": \"invalid_grant\",\n \"error_description\": \"Bad Request\"\n}"}`

I assume it is because the login was done using the package and not through the browser with a redirect to the app afterwards. Now I have no idea how to do this correctly though, that I sign in with the `google_sign_in` package and then use the code to get the tokens from the Sync Gateway. I can't find any helpful information for this problem.

I would be very happy if someone could help me, possibly in a call. Maybe this way something like this can be solved faster.

Comment: You may want to check out these posts on how to implement [implicit flow](https://www.couchbase.com/blog/oidc-implicit-flow-client-authentication-couchbase-sync-gateway/) and [authorization flow](https://www.couchbase.com/blog/oidc-authorization-code-flow-client-authentication-couchbase-sync-gateway/?ref=blog) using Sync Gateway.

Comment: Thank you, I read this some time ago and tried to implement it accordingly.